# In discord, can I maintain a conversation with only one player while listening to the whole group?

Tags: discord

I host a tabletop game using discord and sometimes I feel like I need to pass information directly to a player and not having the others to listening. Is it possible to direct my voice channel to a particular person while still listening to everybody else?

Comment: You can "Deafen" them. Kinda the reverse of mute.

Comment: @Robotnik That's counter productive. The intention is for the flow to not be disrupted. When you deafen everybody, but the person you are relaying the message to, all other players won't be able to hear. They'll likely be confused as to why the channel is suddenly silent and possibly start to chatter as to what's going on, disrupting the private chat. Keep inm nid, a deafened person can still tlak, but can't hear anything. So, the two people who aren't deafened can hear everything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't really have to do with gaming or a specific game, but a separate application entirely, that is not a game.

Comment: @Rapitor Discord is considered on-topic here, there was a recent [meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12989/152051) about it specifically.

Comment: @Virusbomb, wasn't aware of that. Not sure I agree, but meta is law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called whisper functionality, which Discord currently doesn't feature. [Here](https://feedback.discordapp.com/forums/326712-discord-dream-land/suggestions/12321720-whisper) you can vote to have this implemented.

Currently, you have to use one of the following workarounds:

1) Use a voice chat, which has whisper functionality, e.g. teamspeak.

2) Send the player the private message via text. This is cumbersome, but I feel the best solution, if you want to continue using Discord.

3) Call the player via discord. This removes you from the group chat for the  duration of the call.

4) Move the player and you to a secondary audio channel. Also removes you from the group chat and makes it obvious you are relaying a private message to them.

5) Create a second discord account and use that to relay private messages to your players either via option 3 and 4. This allows you to stay in the main channel, but requires mic on/off juggling, whenever you want to send a private message (mute your main account while sending the message, then unmute after having finished)